# joomla 2.5 how to search the kunena component content from main serach bar?

Tags: search, joomla

need to search the content from website and kunena component (both are latest version). The search must be from main search bar (Default by joomla).

How to configure the search query?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to write a Search Plugin for Kunena.  There is already such a plugin for J1.5, and can be seen on this list at the [JED][1].  If they don't have a J2.5 version, it shouldn't be too difficult to download a simple J2.5 plugin from the same list to use as a reference to write your own with the Kunena Tables.